# Assigning vector data attributes from other adjacent data

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.1, spatial-join

I am supposed to do a presentation on how to do this, and I'm not exactly sure what it is asking.

The question is: "how can you assign vector data attributes from other adjacent data?"

I am in a geology field class and am learning GIS and mapping my field sites as well. This is supposed to be something I am able to learn through the help menus and/or forums, but the question itself is not clear to me and they won't answer me. Anyone have an idea what this would most likely be asking?

Answer (score 2):

What they're asking you how to do is called a "Spatial Join".  It's a very common task in GIS software.

You can find the ArcGIS help you need [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000q000000).

Once you have joined the data together, you can update your fields with the joined data.

Now that you know the terminology, you can [search this site](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spatial-join) for more questions relating to the topic.

[Here's a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=solq8CuCbow) on how to perform a spatial join in ArcMap.  Note, this is for version 9.3, but should still be pretty much the same in 10.x.

Comment: Hey thats really helpful! But for some reason I think it may not be join because the next persons topic is "You have 2 sets of vector data that describe one common and many uncommon attributes, how can you make one set of data that describes all of the attributes" - Doesn't that sound a lot like a join? Do you think it would be a relate?

Comment: There are two types of joins - Attribute joins and spatial joins.  Your original question sounds like a spatial join because they say "adjacent data".  The other sounds like an attribute join.

Comment: For additional clarification, these joins also fall into a category of operations that are refered to as conflation  http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Conflation